# best practice of testing with scala (unittests and integration tests)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using playframework to develop a web application with scala.

what are the recomended ways to write unit tests and integration tests?

Are there any good hints, examples?

Frontend is a ReactJS app and Backend the playframework application with REST routes.

thanks in advance.